# Umbraco webserivce returns 405

Tags: javascript, web-services, umbraco

This is probably a noobish question but here goes

I have a phonegap application that requires users to log in. 
The users exist in my umbraco installation. 
I am trying to use this webservice /umbraco/webservices/api/MemberService.asmx?op=UserAuthenticates

this is my javascript from my phonegap app

```
var wsUrl = "http://188.228.44.69/umbraco/webservices/api/MemberService.asmx?op=UserAuthenticates";

var soapRequest = 'POST /umbraco/webservices/api/MemberService.asmx HTTP/1.1 \
    Host: 188.228.44.69 \
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 \
    Content-Length: length \
    SOAPAction: "http://umbraco.org/webservices/UserAuthenticates" \
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
    <soap:Body> \
        <UserAuthenticates xmlns="http://umbraco.org/webservices/"> \
            <username>'+user+'</username> \
            <password>'+password+'</password> \
        </UserAuthenticates>\
    </soap:Body>\
</soap:Envelope>';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: wsUrl,
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapRequest,
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg.LoginResult);
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        console.log("nay "+msg);
    }
});
```

but when i run the code i get 
"OPTIONS MemberService.asmx?op=UserAuthenticates - 405 Method Not Allowed"

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Im running umbraco on windows server 2008 with iis 7

Comment: What device are you testing on? Can you hit the method on a breakpoint or does it error before it gets there?

Comment: :-) I asked this question 6 and a half years ago :-D Im not working on the project anymore. But i was testing on both Android and IOS :p

Comment: Haha, oh yea.. 013! Shame on me.